# Why AES256 with SHA384 in TLS

Tags: tls, cryptography, aes, sha2

Is there any concrete/solid rationale for this choice of cipher?  Seems to be the default when I connect via TLS1.2 to an Apache2 server (whatever latest version on Debian 11) with configuration lines `SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL` and `SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1`

This is part of the output from `openssl s_client -connect server:443 -tls1_2`:

```
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

I'm a little bit puzzled by the choice of AES256 (isn't that overkill? isn't 128-bit considered the standard security level for general Internet communications, including banking/financial communications?)

But I'm really puzzled by the SHA384 — why the mismatch of 192-bit strength of the hash to 256-bit of the AES cipher?  (even if it was a matter of matching the strength to the RSA key size, still: why not then AES-192?)

Comment: These are several questions in one: why this cipher is chosen as default, why AES256 is used of AES128, if AES128 is the standard security level for banking/financial, why pair AES256 with SHA384. Please restrict yourself to a single question only. And for the question about pairing (which seems to be your main point) - this is better suited for [crypto.se].

Answer (score 1):

[As explained in RFC 6460](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6460), there are two levels of minimum cryptographic security for NSA Suite B algorithms in TLS: 128 bit and 192 bit. While AES-192 would have been sufficient in the second level, it is not included in Suite B, so the only choice is AES-256. As to the question why AES-192 is not in Suite B, [this appears to be related to a lack of hardware support at the time of the decision](https://mailarchive.ietf.org/arch/msg/cfrg/lyP6VTm2h1asZSCNn7ogNywD5TU/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a *concrete* rationale for the choice of this cipher suite, but you have a number of misunderstandings about the individual ciphers its made up of.

1. AES-256 is overkill in terms of cryptographic strength today, but is importantly stronger against quantum computers. It is also supported by AES-NI (hardware-accelerated AES in modern CPUs), so the performance difference vs. AES-128 is fairly trivial on anything but minimal-power or very old systems (the bottlenecks will be elsewhere in the system, such as network). There is almost no reason today to ever use less than AES-256 with normal PC or mobile hardware.
2. SHA-384 in this cipher suite does fairly little. It's used only as the "PRF" (pseudo-random function) at a few places during the handshake (deriving the actual keys from the pre-master secret - which I believe truncates the hash anyhow - and the finalization of the handshake to ensure nothing was changed in transit). All bulk data integrity is protected with GCM authentication tags (from the AES-256-GCM symmetric cipher), and both the certificate itself and the ephemeral ECDH public parameter can be signed with any signature scheme that the client will accept, which doesn't appear in the TLS cipher suite at all. (As a side note, RSA is only used for the signing the ECDHE key exchange public parameter.) As such, the security of the hash chosen is much less critical than you may have expected. Given that, selecting SHA2-384 makes at least some sense; it's computed on 64-bit internal state (which is faster than the shorter hashes when computed on modern 64-bit CPUs) while still being highly secure against collisions/birthday attacks. SHA2-512 or SHA2-512/256 would also have been fine, most likely; I'm not sure why this specific hash was chosen.

Comment: The hash in a 1.2 ciphersuite does not determine the signature in ServerKX; that is server-chosen constrained by client extension 13=sigalgs, which _also_ controls cert signatures. (In 1.3 ext 13 continues to control protocol-level signature, now in CertVerify and covering the transcript hash, and new ext 50=sigalgscert controls cert signatures.) For an AEAD 1.2 ciphersuite the hash is used only for key derivation and Finished, called PRF. (In 1.3 similarly the ciphersuite hash is used only for HKDF.)

Comment: Whoops, thank you, I misremembered. Editing